# How do I remove a configuration object from the active configuration?

Tags: 8, entities, configuration

I'm writing a custom module for Drupal 8. It defines a field storage configuration object, in a file called modules/mymod/config/install/field.storage.bloom_stem.bs_twitter_ac.yml.

The problem is that this is not removed when I uninstall the module; it is apparently left behind because, when I re-install the module, I get a crash.

```
drush -y pm-uninstall mymod
drush cr
drush -y en mymod
```

> exception 'Drupal\Core\Config\PreExistingConfigException' with message 'Configuration objects (field.storage.bloom_stem.bs_twitter_ac) provided by mymod already exist in active configuration'

So it seems I need to some how manually remove this configuration object. Do I need to provide some more code that deletes it when the module is uninstalled?

Comment: Looks like a similar problem: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/173684/how-to-remove-mymodule-configurations-on-uninstall

Comment: Easy Install module is there to fix & avoid this issue completely https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_install

Answer (score 58):

The easiest way to do this at the moment is to use `drush php` (or `core-cli`) to open an interactive session.

Then use:

```
Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('system.menu.devel')->delete();
```

[This functionality will be added into Drupal console](https://github.com/hechoendrupal/DrupalConsole/issues/1366) as well.

Comment: This perfectly solved the problem. Change 'system.menu.devel' to `the_setting.you.want.to.delete'

Comment: What about removing multiple configs? e.g. `migrate_plus.migration.*`

Comment: @Nic it's not pretty, but check out my solution on your other question to delete multiple: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/214132/is-there-a-way-with-drush-or-console-to-delete-all-active-config-with-a-certain

Comment: If you have direct access to the database, very carefully delete the offending entries from the `config` table.

Answer (score 34):

Drush command to delete configuration object: `drush config-delete <config_name>`.

Comment: in cases of multi-site, `drush -l your.site.domain config-delete <config_name>`

Comment: shortened format is `drush cdel <config_name>`

Comment: be mindful, if you delete any configs, you should also do a `drush cr` after to remove any cached config dependencies otherwise you may get something that looks like this: `Error: Call to a member function getConfigDependencyKey() on null`

Answer (score 17):

You can use the following methods.
Use the following code in hook_uninstall

```
Drupal::configFactory()->reset('field.storage.bloom_stem.bs_twitter_ac');
```

OR

in the yml file you can put the dependencies like

```
dependencies:
  module:
    - yourmodule
  enforced:
    module:
      - yourmodule
```

then drupal will automatically remove this configurations on uninstalling your module as described by Berdir here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/173879/10436

Comment: This might have changed lately, but it is slightly different now.

dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - yourmodule

Comment: @hw your comment is very important. Consider adding it to the answer, with a link to the relevant change record if possible. I couldn't find it.

Comment: GAH!! I knew there was a way to do this, but I couldn't remember the "enforced:" part. This is the simplest, cleanest way to do it, especially when creating them in yml files.

Comment: using this approach and trying to install the module, Drupal throws the error: Module custom_module cannot be enabled because it depends on the following modules which could not be found:

Comment: Hi John, in case you didn't end up figuring it out, it sounds as though you may have put your module dependency in the wrong place. 

The configuration described in this answer is intended to go in YML file(s) in the config/install directory in your module. In the OP's case this would be in his/her config/install/field.storage.bloom_stem.bs_twitter_ac.yml file.

It sounds as though you may have put the dependency in your module's mymodule.info.yml file instead (that will prevent your module from being able to install)

Comment: NOTE: when using features, many of the config/install/*.yml files it generates will depend on some other config in the same directory (e.g. a field config will have the corresponding field storage config listed as a dependency). In these cases it is sufficient to add the enforced module dependency to the last config in the chain (the field storage config in this case). (i.e. if a.yml lists b.yml as a config: dependency, then you only need to add the enforced module to b.yml - not to both).

Comment: It should be noted this doesn't work to remove the parent config with `Drupal::configFactory()->reset(...);` but does with `Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable(...)->delete();`.  Also, with a lot of config files, it doesn't make sense to put dependencies in every file.  A better approach would be to loop through all the configs to delete in a hook_uninstall function.

Answer (score 10):

Using the [drupal console](https://drupalconsole.com/):

```
$ drupal config:delete 'the_config_to_delete'
```

Comment: Docs at: https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/content/en/commands/config-delete.html But can it do wildcards? e.g. `drupal config:delete 'migrate_plus.migration.*'`

Comment: In the latest drupal console, config:delete expects you to specify the config *type* first, e.g. `drupal config:delete active 'name'` or `drupal config:delete staging 'name' (with only one parameter supplied, it'll assume you've given it the type and prompt you for the config name.)

Answer (score 8):

Drupal::configFactory()->reset() does not delete the config object.
For this run `Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('field.storage.node.your_field_name')->delete()`

Answer (score 4):

## Uninstall Active Configuration from Custom Module

I ran into the same problem trying to uninstall config files from a custom module. I have a custom module used to pass custom configuration files for webform. Since I'm not perfect I want to be able to uninstall the module, edit code and reinstall. I found if I referenced my custom module (my_module) in the dependencies/enforced section in the config/install yml file, when I uninstalled my module the configuration files would also uninstall.

```
   langcode: en
    status: true
    dependencies:
        enforced:
            module:
                - webform
                - my_module // reference your module here
```

Answer (score 4):

I created a simple module that you can use to delete configuration items.

https://www.drupal.org/project/config_delete

Answer (score 4):

Use [hook_uninstall](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_uninstall/8.2.x) to remove the configuration, when the module is uninstalled.

Then delete the configuration:

```
function hook_uninstall() {
  \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('the_setting.you.want.to.delete')->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can remove all the configs you imported from config/install by implementing HOOK_uninstall():

```
function my_module_uninstall() {

  $module_path = \Drupal::service('extension.list.module')->getPath('my_module') . '/config/install';

  $configs = [];
  $files = \Drupal::service('file_system')->scanDirectory($module_path, '/\.yml$/');

  if ($files) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $configs[] = $file->name;
    }

    foreach ($configs as $config_name) {
        \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable($config_name)->delete();
    }

    return TRUE;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is the answer! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use Drupal console to delete the active configuration, with `drupal config:delete active config_to_delete`.

Answer (score 2):

All these answers recommend deleting the underlying config object directly, but the correct way is to delete the entity through the entity storage system.

For example, if you have an image style with ID "large" and you want to delete it, you should do this:

```
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('image_style')->load('large')->delete();
```

Doing it this way, core will invoke "predelete" before the config is deleted and "delete" hooks after the config is deleted, which other modules may rely on to perform various clean up operations.

Comment: Saved my day thank you

Answer (score 1):

Search for all the configurations listed using
**drush config-list**
Then identify the configuration that you would like to delete.
Use the below command to delete the configuration
**drush config-delete**

Answer (score 1):

I could delete the active configuration using the drush config:delete command as below 
`drush cdel "name of the config"` 
for example in my case it was
`drush cdel dtn_apple_news.setting`

after running this the configuration got deleted and then running `drush en-y "module name"` got the module to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Easy Install module](https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_install) to avoid this configuration issues, this module will allow to delete configurations while uninstalling a module, it works even if a module's configs not contains **enforced** in yml or not added configs in **optional** folder.

[image: Configuration on uninstallation image]

Answer (score -1):

I leave here a tiny (yet a bit over-engineered) Python script which removes the configuration leftovers. It relies on `drush config-delete`.

```
# 'batch_config_delete.py'
# 'drush' has to be available in the current directory

import os
import argparse
import subprocess

MODULES_ROOT = "/var/www/html/MYSITE/web/modules/custom"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Batch config delete.")
    parser.add_argument("-m", "--module", required=True, help="Module name")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    install_path = os.path.join(MODULES_ROOT, args.module, 'config/install')

    for f in os.listdir(install_path):
        if f.endswith('.yml'):
            config_name = os.path.splitext(f)[0]
            print "Delete config:", config_name
            subprocess.call(['drush', 'config-delete', config_name])
```

Should be executed like this:

```
python ../scripts/batch_config_delete.py -m foobar
```

Comment: You are asking PHP developers to use a python script? Seems a bit silly.

Comment: Why Python on a PHP project?