# In custom install profile How to delete the "Footer" menu that core provides by default?

Tags: 8, distributions, installation-profiles

I am writing custom Drupal 8 install profile to be used in our organization.

The core creates the "Footer" menu as default system menu listed in menu admin page.

I want to delete or disable this menu during installation execution.

I already found that I can make it manually delete able if I add system.menu.footer.yml with

`locked: false`

But how can I eliminate it in the first place, via install profile ?

Answer (score 3):

Solved.

Following https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/186322/8938  I added the code below to  my_profile_install() function inside my_profile.install file.

`\Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('system.menu.footer')->delete();`

Reinstalled and yes, footer menu is not around anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: the OP asked how to do this in an install profile. For that please see [the other answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/219716/18571).*

Using [Drush](https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/config/config:delete/):

```
drush config-delete 'system.menu.footer'
```

The [Drupal console](https://drupalconsole.com/docs/en/commands/config-delete) should work the same:

```
drupal config:delete 'system.menu.footer'
```

The same commands could be used to delete other system menus as well. E.g., `drush config-delete 'system.menu.main'`