# How to remove field from form and configuration?

Tags: 8, forms, hooks, configuration

We have a custom module, `mymodule` that has a form, `mymoduleForm` with two fields: `enabled content types` and `urls`.

We no longer need the `enabled content types` field on the form and want to remove it from the form and configuration. We do not have either `config/install/mymodule.settings.yml` and `config/schema/mymodule.schema.yml` files.

**How can we remove the field (`enabled content types`) from both the form and configuration?**

`mymoduleForm.php` (all lines below we are thinking need to be removed related to `enabled_content_types`)

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $mymodule_config = $this->config('mymodule.settings');

  $types = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('node_type')
    ->loadMultiple();

  foreach($types as $type) {
    $content_types[$type->id()] = $type->label();
  }

  $form['enabled_content_types'] = [
    '#type' => 'checkboxes', 
    '#title' => $this->t('Enabled Content Types'),
    '#description' => $this->t('content types .'),
    '#default_value' => $config->get('enabled_content_types'),
    '#options' => $content_types,
  ];

  ...

  return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
}

public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $mymodule_config = $this->config('mymodule.settings');
  $mymodule_config
    ->set('enabled_content_types', $form_state->getValue('enabled_content_types'))
    ->set('urls', $form_state->getValue('urls'))
    ->save();

  parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this line

```
->set('enabled_content_types', $form_state->getValue('enabled_content_types'))
```

to

```
->clear('enabled_content_types')
```

In Drupal, go to config form and click save.

**Side Note:** Alternatively, you could also delete the config via Drupal Console or Drush as mentioned in the answers here, [How do I remove a configuration object from the active configuration?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164612/how-do-i-remove-a-configuration-object-from-the-active-configuration)

Now you may now remove the relevant code.

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $mymodule_config = $this->config('mymodule.settings');

  $types = \Drupal::entityTypeManager() // remove
    ->getStorage('node_type') // remove
    ->loadMultiple(); // remove

  foreach($types as $type) { // remove
    $content_types[$type->id()] = $type->label(); // remove
  } // remove

  $form['enabled_content_types'] = [ // remove
    '#type' => 'checkboxes', // remove 
    '#title' => $this->t('Enabled Content Types'), // remove
    '#description' => $this->t('content types .'), // remove
    '#default_value' => $config->get('enabled_content_types'), // remove
    '#options' => $content_types, // remove
  ]; // remove

  ...

  return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
}

public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $mymodule_config = $this->config('mymodule.settings');
    ->clear('enabled_content_types') // remove
    ->set('urls', $form_state->getValue('urls'))
    ->save();
  parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);
}
```

Comment: if i do this in my local development environment, would i have to do the same steps in our cloud Dev environment? For example (local dev), if change line to be `clear()`, save the form, and remove all the lines, i would not have to replicate that after deploying those changes to our cloud dev environment, correct?

Comment: @usernameabc yes, correct. If you don't want to do that, you could also use Drupal Console or Drush as the answers in [How do I remove a configuration object from the active configuration?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164612/how-do-i-remove-a-configuration-object-from-the-active-configuration) point out. It would be `Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('mymodule.settings')->clear('enabled_content_types');`. OR you could use Devel module and paste this in the execute php and then uninstall devel, since you don't want that module enabled in production

Comment: `Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('mymodule.settings')->clear('enabled_content_types');` that along with the removal of the code did it for us and we were able to get it done successfully.